# Flatlist not updating when the data is changed

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have an issue when I update the item's Quantity then set array, FlatList is not Updating
also, extraData is not working for me I have tried so many things to fix it, but still not working
check the code for adding quantity function below:

```
const handleAdd = (message) => {
//add Quantity for items

let items = list;
let index = items.findIndex((el) => el._id == message._id);
items[index] = {
  ...items[index],
  sellingQuantity: parseInt(items[index].sellingQuantity) + 1,
};
setList(items);
```

};

and here is the FlatList

```
<FlatList
          data={list}
          keyExtractor={(message) => message._id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItemSelling
              title={title}
              barcode={item.barcode}
              description={item.description}
              price={item.price1}
              quantity={item.sellingQuantity}
              totalPrice={item.totalPrice}
              renderLeftActions={() => (
                <View style={styles.swipeLeft}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleDelete(item)}>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons
                      name="trash-can"
                      size={30}
                      color={colors.white}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              )}
              renderRightActions={() => (
                <View style={styles.swipeRight}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAdd(item)}>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons
                      name="plus"
                      size={30}
                      color={colors.white}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleDeduct(item)}>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons
                      name="minus"
                      size={30}
                      color={colors.white}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              )}
            />
          )}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding another function to count total

```
const countTotal = () => {
let element = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  element += list[i].totalPrice;
}
setTotalItems(element);
console.log(element);
};
```

then adding countTotal(); in the handleAdd() function